# How to disable "untranslated message" warnings from Flutter gen-l10n for country files

Tags: flutter, localization, arb

The specific case I'm looking at is two `.arb` language files: `en` and `en_AU`. `en` includes all the translation tokens and `en_AU` includes only a few that are actually different. This works as expected: with `en_AU` locale `en` tokens are used when no alternate translation provided.

However, when running `flutter gen-l10n` it gives the `untranslated message(s)` warning for `en_AU`. Is there a way to turn this off, while preserving the warning for different languages?

Answer (score 1):

Create `l10n.yaml` file in the project root and add below code

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
nullable-getter: false
untranslated-messages-file: l10n_errors.txt
```

run `flutter gen-l10n` it will general `l10n_errors.txt` file and you can see untranslated items.

Answer (score 0):

Below answer is based on the usage of `flutter_localizations`

pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
```

Create a file named `l10n.yaml` in your root location.

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n/translations. // where all translation exists
template-arb-file: app_en.arb. // default file to consider as template
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart //generated output file which contains getters for all the translation keys
untranslated-messages-file: untranslated_keys // this line of code will removing the warnings, but it will generate the file named untranslated_keys with details on which files missing what keys
```

Please follow the comments on each line to understand the purpose.

Example snippet of untranslated_keys

```
{
  "de": [
    "homePage_title",
    "homePage_header",
    "login_button_title",
  ],

  "es": [
    "homePage_title",
    "homePage_header",
  ],

  "fr": [
     "homePage_title",
    "homePage_header",
  ],
}
```

This will help you understand what translations are missing which could potentially break behaviour on specific locales.

Refer https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_localization

Answer (score -1):

How about you just provide translartions ffor these different languages. The linter is clearly notifying you that you didn't provide some translations. All you have to do is translate it. If you're finding difficulty figuring out which one you didn't translate, you could just use Chat GPT